# How can I add plot legends to my list plot?

Tags: plotting, legending

I would like to add a legend to the `ListPlot` defined in the code shown below. Unfortunately, adding `PlotLegends -> Automatic` to the plot does not work. I was wondering if there are any other ways to add a legend to this plot.

```
points = 
  Join[
    RandomVariate[
      MultinormalDistribution[{-0.5, 0.25}, 0.07 IdentityMatrix[2]], 1000], 
    RandomVariate[
      MultinormalDistribution[{0.6, -0.1}, 0.03 IdentityMatrix[2]], 1000], 
    RandomReal[{-1.5, 1.5}, {1000, 2}]]; 
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[points]; 
ListPlot[points, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[PDF[skd, {x, y}]]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Comment: points = Join[
   RandomVariate[
    MultinormalDistribution[{-0.5, 0.25}, 0.07*IdentityMatrix[2]], 
    1000], RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{0.6, -0.1}, 0.03*IdentityMatrix[2]], 
    1000], RandomReal[{-1.5, 1.5}, {1000, 2}]]
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[points]
ListPlot[points,  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[PDF[skd, {x, y}]]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AspectRatio -> 1]

Comment: Perhaps you want PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Hue[#] &, {0, 1}}]?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a legend to any expression with `Legended`. Like so:

```
Legended[
  ListPlot[points,
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[PDF[skd, {x, y}]]],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    AspectRatio -> 1],
  BarLegend[{Hue, {0, 1}}]]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1]
points =  Join[
   RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{-0.5, 0.25}, 0.07 IdentityMatrix[2]], 1000], 
   RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{0.6, -0.1}, 0.03 IdentityMatrix[2]], 1000], 
   RandomReal[{-1.5, 1.5}, {1000, 2}]]; 

skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[points];
```

To get a bar legend that matches the pdf values of `skd`  (1) use `points` with `SmoothDensityHistogram` with the options `ColorFunction -> Hue` and `PlotLegends -> Automatic` and (2) take the second part of the output:

```
legend = SmoothDensityHistogram[points, 
    ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotLegends -> Automatic][[2]]
```

[image]

Then we  use `PlotLegends -> legend` with `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[points, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[PDF[skd, {x, y}]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotLegends -> legend]
```

[image]